# Yet another AdMob 4.3.1 "you must have AdActivity" issue-

Tags: android, eclipse

I have read every single question on here about the "you must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges" error.

I've also tried every single solution offered.  Changed the target sdk in project.properties, etc.

I'm stumped.  Not that it is any different than all the others, but here is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
  >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
          />
</application>
```

Using version 4.3.1.  Have created the libs folder, added the jar, did project clean, exited and restarted eclipse, EVERYTHING I could think of.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

adMob AdActivity should be like this...

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: Hi, if I enter all those, Eclipse tells me:  Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|
 screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize'). While the LogCat asks me to declare them if I leave them out. Any clue?